# How to solve Non-Linear model in Java with Apache Commons or other?

Tags: java, apache-commons, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I have a sample of Time and Temperature (x,y), and I need know how time the temperature is equals at Z degrees celcius ( ex.: 35 C ).

My sample colleted is little, for start of calculus I use the 3 samples. Follow:

```
Temperature | Time (s)
    25      |  0 
    27      |  10 
    33      |  17
    40      |  ?
```

I know that I need more samples for exactly results, but for start I use this.

The question is, how I implement a code for this ? I learn about Apache Commons like:

org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar
But I don't know how to use this lib.
I need a example of code for calculus this.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you need to build Pattern based on the known data, and use the Pattern to get the last time. This is the simplest problem for machine learning. You can try WEKA.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to achieve, it seems like you're making a simple problem complex.

The easiest way to solve your problem would be to treat it as a [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) problem and use the [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression) Apache Commons class to do something like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class MySimpleRegression {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a Simple Regression object 
        SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression();

        // create your data object with various instances of x, y - make the 
        // variable you want to predict the 'y' in your data
        // i.e. if you wanna predict the time at a given temperature, 
        // 'x' would be temperature and 'y' time

        double[][] data = { { 25, 0 }, {27, 10 }, {33, 17 }, {40, 20 }};

        // pass this data to your simple regression object
        simpleRegression.addData(data);

        // and then you can predict the time at a given temperature value
        System.out.println("Predicted Time: "  + simpleRegression.predict(35));

        // You can also get the slope and intercept from your data
        System.out.println("slope = " + simpleRegression.getSlope());
        System.out.println("intercept = " + simpleRegression.getIntercept());
    }
}
```

This seems like a more straightforward way to solve your problem. Hopefully this helps you or somebody else.

P.S.: Didn't try running this. Should work just fine though.